# How does Hibernate create query? How to Avoid reaching limit of 61 table?

Tags: java, hibernate, join, spring-data-jpa

I have a Java Class X which is actually an Entity that is connected to Spring Data JPA. 
It has annotation: @Entity (javax.persistence.Entity)

Lately, we have added a column/member to this class, and that caused that when this class is fetched from database with Spring DataJPA (I'm not quite sure how to call it), I get the known error:

> Exception: Too many tables; MariaDB can only use 61 tables in a join - could not extract ResultSet

I don't need so many joins, I simply understood that JPA creates many joins to be on the safer side.

My question is: 
How do I minimize my class to make wisely in a way that tere would be less joins?

I went over the members of my Class X,

and found there were 25 fields which connect to other "class-Entity tables".

Some are of OneToMany relationship and some of ManyToOne.

So that's not 61.

I noticed that the above error was roused when trying to fetch other entity-class Y, that two of it's members are of type X.

I tried minimizing one of the members of entity-class X, but it didn't help.

So that's my other question included:
How does JPA create it's auto generated query (as explained [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.11.0.M1/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation))?
Understanding this will make things much clearer and simpler for me to avoid this error, tackle the error if it shows, and more important - to organize my class entities more efficiently.

Thank-you!

Comment: Are you fetching these OneToMany entities eagerly?
Do they also fetch other entities eagerly?

Comment: what is default (eager or lazy)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate is very good at building queries to get just the data that is needed, so if it creates a join with more than 61 tables you really have a problem with your entities!

If your entity A has a B and B has a C then Hibernate may try to read both A, B and C in the same query. This is called an eager load. It is often the right thing to do in order to avoid round trips, but if you have many references to other entities it may be problematic.

The way I see it you have two options. The first is to reduce the number of references to other entities you have. The other is to mark some entities for lazy loading. That way they should not be loaded in the main select. However, if you need them they will be fetched later on, possibly leading to many follow-up selects. That can be expensive as well.

It is hard to be more specific without knowing your entities, but start trying to clean up the model and then read up on lazy loading. Good luck!

Comment: In the example you gave "If your entity A has a B and B has a C", - would it help A to reduce entities in B? Thank-you

Comment: Yes. If A refers to B and B refers to C and D and E and all are loaded eagerly then loading A will load A, B, C, D and E. Making B only refer to C will reduce that to A, B and C.

Comment: The thing is I have reduced the class and 61 joins limit is still reached. That is the reason for the other half of my question: How do I do the "math" myself to understand how it reaches 61 joins (we have many tables and relationships)??

Comment: Check what is loaded eagerly and what is not and see how you would read everything manually with a single SQL. Again, if you can't reduce the number of relationships a lot, try to switch to lazy-loading for some entities instead. Chances are you don't need all of them for a given use case if you have that many!